# How can i add linkedin social login with aws cognito pool ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to add linked in social login with cognito user pool  using node? I Want to know whole process about it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. As AWS coginito doesn't support Linkedin as external federated identity providers, moreover Linkedin has no support for OpenID connect.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html

Comment: is there any way I can do that with identity pool  ?

Comment: Not that i am aware of